# Updating Values in An Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to update the reviewCount on each array to 1. I am confused why my foreach loop will not update it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

$output:

```
Array(
    [1] => Array(
        [category] => Category 1
        [country] => USA
        [date] => 2012-04-07 23:50:49
        [name] => Product 1
        [reviewCount] => 
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [category] => Category 1
        [country] => USA
        [date] => 2012-04-07 23:50:49
        [name] => Product 1
        [reviewCount] => 
)
```

Code:

```
foreach ($output as $row) {
    $row['reviewCount'] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not update it inside `$output` because you are setting the review count on a *copy* of the row. Do this instead:

```
foreach ($output as &$row) { // <-- added &
    $row['reviewCount'] = 1;
}
```

This way you are operating on a reference to the row, which has the same effect of operating on the original row itself. See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for more details.

Another way to do the same (more intuitive possibly, although "worse" technically) would be

```
foreach ($output as $key => $row) {
    $output[$key]['reviewCount'] = 1;
}
```

This way you are operating on the original row again -- obviously, since you are fetching it from inside the array manually using its key.

Comment: I'm interested, how is it "worse"? Could you please elaborate? :)

Comment: @NiftyDude: It performs one more lookup. Not much of a problem, so quotes around worse.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way that doesn't use reference: (`&`)

```
foreach($output as $i => $row) {
   $output[$i]['reviewCount'] = 1;
}
```